# How to get rid of a sprite but so I can add it again later

Tags: javascript, sprite

I need to make it so the rocket flies which I want to achive by killing the sprite subtracting a y cordinate and drawing the sprite and doing that over and over again so this way I get an illusion of it flying up.

```
background(rgb(49,0,71));

var sn = 0; 


while ((sn <= 100)) {
  var star = createSprite(200, 200);
  star.y = randomNumber(0,400);
  star.x = randomNumber(0,400);
  star.setAnimation("star");
  
  star.scale = 0.09;
  
  drawSprites();
  sn = sn + 1;
}

var rocket1 = createSprite(randomNumber(0,400), 400);
rocket1.setAnimation("rocket1");
rocket1.rotation = 270;
rocket1.scale = 0.2;

**function rocket1m() {
  rocket1.destroy();
  rocket1.y = rocket1.y - 1;
  drawSprites();
}**
rocket1m();
drawSprites();
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What work, what don't ?

Comment: I think we need some more information. This is not standard javascript and I think this is also not the full code. Where are you executing this code?